# Finding Minimal polynomial from Characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

1. If $T$ is a linear operator with characteristic polynomial $(x^2-1)^6$ such that $\mathrm{rank}(T-I) = 9$, $\mathrm{rank}(T-I)^2 = 7$, $\mathrm{rank}(T +I) = 10$ and $\mathrm{rank}(T +I)^2 = 9$, find the minimal polynomial of T?
2. Let $V$ be the vector space of functions on the real line spanned by the basis $B = \lbrace \sin x,\cos x,x\sin x,x\cos x\rbrace$. Let $T$ be defined by $Tf = f''$, where $f''$ denotes the second derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. Determine the minimal polynomial of $T$?

I tried for both the problems and I am guessing (not 100% sure) that the Minimal polynomial will be $(x-1)^3(x+1)^2$ for Question 1.

For Question 2, characteristic polynomial will be $(-1-\lambda)³(-1-\lambda)$ and Minimal polynomial will be $(-1-λ)^2$.

Kindly verify and let me know if I am correct or wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: What is the minimal polynomial of a linear operator?